# Try/Except para columna no existente

Tags: python, pandas, excepciones

quiero gestionar el error cuando se selecciona una columna que no existe (supongase data['columna1'] o data.columna1).

```
try:
    data[[i for i in list(data.columns)]]
except KeyError:
    print('No existe esta columna')
```

Quería hacerlo de forma sencilla. Intentándolo con este código, si pruebo a introducir una columna inexistente (data['noexieste']) sigue saltando el KeyError predefinido.

Saludos, gracias.

Comment: La forma extremadamente sencilla `existe = True if "columna1" in data.columns else False` En este caso la variable `existe` toma el valor de `True` si la columna se encuentra de lo contrario es `false`. Si quieres generar una excepción entonces lleva este código a un `if/else` normal y genera la excepción con `raise KeyError("columna inexistente")`

Comment: Pero quería hacerlo con try/except. Gracias

Comment: ¿y con el código que compartes cual es el problema?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho el problema es que no genera la exepcón, lo que hace ahí es generar una lista de las columnas que tiene su dataframe, le falta comprabar (usar `if`) y generar la excepcion

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta @PatricioMoracho. Le daré un par de vueltas

Comment: @Christian podrías aclararme un poco más como usar if en mi código, no lo he conseguido. Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te voy a mostrar 2 formas de hacerlo. La primera es con un `if` y la segunda es accediendo a la posición

```py
if "columna1" in data.columns:
    pass
    #haces algo
else:
    raise KeyError("la columna no existe")
```

Para este caso genera,os una excepción en caso la columna no existe, si quieres puedes poner un `try/except` pero no le veo mucho sentido, mejor es quitar el `raise` y poner un `print()`

La segunda forma es accediendo al índice y ver si eso genera una excepción

```py
try:
    data["columna1"]
    #puedes hacer algo más
except KeyError:
    print('No existe esta columna')
```

Comment: Gracias Christian. Lo que yo trataba de hacer es generalizar esta expresión, es decir, tu código verifica columna1, pero a mi me gustaría que verifiase cualquier texto, no se si esto es posible o excede los límites del try/except

Comment: Si es posible, solo pon una variable y listo

Comment: No estaba comprendiendo bien el funcionamiento del try/except. Pensaba que por decrilo así, se generaba una regla para el resto del código, y no. Gracias.